# Replace segment of text, across multiple lines between two strings - regex

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-code

I am currently struggling to get my regex to match both everything between two strings and **then** match multiple lines inside of this first match.

So I am trying to go from this

```
if
{
  // A comment 
  foo(c.AAA);
  bar(c.AAA);
  foobar(c.AAA);
}
else 
{
  foo(c.AAA);
  bar(c.AAA);
  foobar(c.AAA);
}
```

To this

```
if
{
  // A comment 
  foo(c.BBB);
  bar(c.BBB);
  foobar(c.BBB);
}
else 
{
  foo(c.AAA);
  bar(c.AAA);
  foobar(c.AAA);
}
```

I am able to match everything **between** the comment and the word ELSE.

But I then want to be able to Match "c.AAA" and replace it with "c.BBB" in a bulk way.

Any Help would be appreciated!

**Edit:** For clarity I just wanted to add that the code I am specifically using is c# and the find and replace is happening across a large number of files. I didn't mention it earlier as I am still interested in finding if this is possible with regex

Comment: You can replace with the 'find in selection' toggle enabled

Comment: Find in selection is super handy, but I need to do this across a large amount of files, so sadly it doesn't really help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your code

```cpp
auto arg = c.AAA;
if (xyz) {
  arg = c.BBB;
}
foo(arg);
bar(arg);
foobar(arg);
```

**Edit**

For C# you could write

```csharp
var arg = c.AAA;
if (xyz) {
  arg = c.BBB;
}
foo(arg);
bar(arg);
foobar(arg);
```

**Edit 2**

It can be done with Regex but I could not get it working with VSC.

With Notepad++ the regex search with *negated character set* includes the newline.

In Notepad++ you have `Find in Files` in the `Find/Replace` dialog and it shows the number of replacements made in the files. Select the checkbox `Follow current doc` and maybe `In all sub-folders`

**Find:** `(// A comment[^}]+?)c\.AAA`

**Replace:** `\1c.BBB`

**Search Mode:** Regular Expression

Apply this Find/Replace until the number of replacements is 0

Comment: This seems like a good solution, but I have made edits to say that I am using c#, so sadly this decltype method wont work for me.

Comment: @Mi-krater In C# it is called `var arg = C.AAA;`

Comment: Ah right. I feel so silly. While I'm not doing it in the exact same way as you have, the logic is the same.
I still want to know if what I wanted was even possible using regex, but I will accept your answer! 
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Mi-krater I found a solution with regex but using Notepad++

Comment: Ahh very clever. 
Both of your options seem perfect for what i was trying to do. Thanks a whole lot, this will help me heaps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a method to achieve this with a single regex, but you could get it done with a small Python script.
First, you would split your text into chunks using the two strings as delimiters:

```
import re

text = """if
{
  // A comment 
  foo(c.AAA);
  bar(c.AAA);
  foobar(c.AAA);
}
else 
{
  foo(c.AAA);
  bar(c.AAA);
  foobar(c.AAA);
}
"""

chunks = re.split(r'(// A comment|else)', text)
```

Which would give:
`['\nif\n{\n  ', '// A comment', ' \n  foo(c.AAA);\n  bar(c.AAA);\n  foobar(c.AAA);\n}\n', 'else', ' \n{\n  foo(c.AAA);\n  bar(c.AAA);\n  foobar(c.AAA);\n}\n']`

And then you can use a loop to modify the part between the delimiters and produce the final string:

```
output = chunks[0]
prev = chunks[0]
for c in chunks[1:]:
    if prev == "// A comment":
        c = c.replace("c.AAA", "c.BBB")
    output += c
    prev = c

print(output)
```